# Inheriting from a WPF Window or User Control

Tags: wpf, inheritance, window

Is there a way to inherit from a WPF Window or UserControl that has XAML associated wit it?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Inheritance in terms of XAML does not makes sense, there are other facilities but please give more details of what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noope.  Only the most derived class can be associated with the XAML.  This is because the XAML system instantiates the code-behind instance.  You can inherit from non-XAML associated UserControl and Control base classes.

The recommended approach for separating the code inheritance vs. the look and feel inheritance is to use custom styles.  These have inheritance via the BasedOn attribute.